# Finding out more about Haynes, Sparrell & Co letterhead from 1901 in Boston?

Tags: united-states, massachusetts, 1900s-decade

Sparrell is a fairly rare last name so I google seach it occasionally and search on various sites. On ebay I ran across an envelope from "Hayes, Sparrell & Co." to A.J. Ives, Brandon, VT postmarked in Boston, MA on Jun 3, 1901 (back when it cost 2 cents to mail a letter). The return address is:

```
Haynes, Sparrell & Co. 
301 Congress St.
Boston, Massachusetts
```

How do I find out more about this company and which Sparrell is on the masthead?

Comment: My grandfather was a director of the sparrel print do in the 1930s. Would like to know more. Best info I have that he was a business man that lived in Boston.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want to know, but here is what I found: 
[image]

*From http://news.google.com/newspapers?nid=2513&dat=19081113&id=2clGAAAAIBAJ&sjid=vf0MAAAAIBAJ&pg=1115,4254749*

So, this (along with other adds) leads me to believe they were a shoe company specializing in rubber soled shoes and boots.

I also found an entry in an [1893 New England Telephone directory](http://www.ebooksread.com/authors-eng/new-england-telephone-and-telegraph-company/official-directory-long-distance-telephone--volume-jul-1893-ewe/page-13-official-directory-long-distance-telephone--volume-jul-1893-ewe.shtml):

> Haynes, Sparrell & Co Boots & Shoes

Here is a [patent](http://books.google.com/books?id=axF9AAAAMAAJ) from 1908 filed by Haynes, Sparrell & Co.

So they were in business at least from 1893-1908.

**Eureka**

A 1911 paper stating:

> **George R. Sparrell**, of the old firm of Haynes, Sparrell & Co., is representing Dunham Bros. Co. in Greater Boston. *(emphasis mine)*

He was possibly married to  Ella B Sparrell, but I have no solid proof yet.

Answer (score 0):

[Sparrell Print [image: Sparrell Print Post Card (reverse)]Post card][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FReu7.jpg)

Based on this advertising card, The Sparrell Print in Boston was an advertising company of some kind. Would like to know more.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH:SE.  The address of The Sparrell Print in Boston doesn't match the address of the company in the question, which makes this look more like a new question, rather than an answer to this question.